# SQL query returning all items when it should return none

Tags: mysql

So my query:

```
select * 
from csci_section 
where number = 4538
```

Should not match any of the items in my table. None of the values in number is 4538. However, the query returns the entire table. I am new to SQL so I am not sure why this response is occurring. Can someone explain why this is happening or how I should adjust my query? I am trying to handle a situation when a user enters a number that does not exist in the database.

Comment: What is the type of the field "number" ?

Comment: your code appears correct, unless there's a charastic of `csci_section.number` that I'm unaware of

Comment: I assume it is an int. The table "csci_section" was provided by our teacher. Is there a way to check what type of field it is?

Comment: Could you please post some schema and records? What are the actual values of the number column when you view the result set?

Comment: You can check with: DESC csci_section

Comment: I actually just figured it out. I had '4538' instead of 4538. Out of curiosity why did the single quotes adjust the result?